# OpenCV VideoCapture set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) taking some time

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, video-capture, dataloader

I am training a deep learning model and was using the following function: Video_Capture.set(). The data took too long to load so I tried investigating the step which consumed the most time.

The following line of code is too slow:

```
vid_cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, start_frame)
```

I use this to start converting a number of frames to tensors.

This step alone is taking around 0.25 seconds on average, and I want to reduce it. Is there anyway I could do that? Other libraries or something.

Let me know if more information would be helpful.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: this is **seeking in a video file**. expect it to be slow or inaccurate. that is a fact of video files. why do you think you need this? by the way, 0.25 seconds isn't that bad for this operation.

Comment: video files are typically encoded in a way that there are some keyframes and some intermediate frames. To get the image of sn intermediate frame, all frames since the previous keyframe have to be decoded.